# Pointing CodeLite to new compiler (GCC 4.8.x)

Tags: c++11, compiler-construction, g++, codelite

I am running **[CodeLite](http://codelite.org/)** 5.2 on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (downgraded from 13.04, which has some stability problems right now).

I just installed the GCC 4.8 compiler, which is not the default GCC compiler on 12.04. I need this compiler to get all the C++ 11 features it supports and were there by default with the compiler that comes with 13.04, using the ‘-std=c++11' switch.

So now I have 4.8 compiler installed, but I can't figure out how to tell CodeLite to use that compiler instead of the default GCC compiler that comes with 12.04 (4.4.x?). How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From our Linux guru in the office:

These commands should be run as the superuser (`sudo`):

```
apt-get install g++-4.8.1

update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-4.6 100

update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-4.8.1 50

update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.6 100

update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.8.1 50

update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/cpp cpp-bin /usr/bin/cpp-4.6 100

update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/cpp cpp-bin /usr/bin/cpp-4.8.1 50

update-alternatives --set g++ /usr/bin/g++-4.8.1

update-alternatives --set gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.8.1

update-alternatives --set cpp-bin /usr/bin/cpp-4.8.1
```

Answer (score 1):

I just discovered the existence of [*CodeLite*](http://codelite.org/) by reading your question.

I found very quickly the [instructions to use `clang` in CodeLite](http://codelite.org/LiteEditor/ClangCompiler)

Just follow them, substituting `gcc-4.8` (or your full path to your `gcc` 4.8) for `clang` and `g++-4.8` for `clang++`

BTW, I hope you did compile GCC 4.8.1 with the `--program-suffix=-4.8` option to its `..../configure`  script.

Comment: Will check out. IMO codelite is the best open source C++ IDE out there right now. Does a lot of things that Code::Blocks does not, particularly refactoring options and class generation wizards, etc. Also behaves better with Qt. Will check out your links. (I am very lazy about finding things...) I did not have to compile GCC 4.8 - check this out. http://askubuntu.com/questions/271388/how-to-install-gcc-4-8-in-ubuntu-12-04-from-the-terminal. Link is 4 months old - I substituted 4.8 for 4.7 in aptitude and it worked.